# How to get maximum value of a text file using (foreach) loop?

Tags: file, powershell, loops, max

The text file is numbers.txt:

```
1;2;5;6;1;3
9;6;16;9;2
6;23;3
3;8;9
```

My code is:

```
$a = Get-Content .\numbers.txt
$maximum = 0
foreach ($i in $a) {
    if ([int]$i.Split(";") -gt $maximum) {
        $maximum = $i.Split(";")
    }
}
$maximum
```

I know, there is something wrong with the types (string-integer), but I don't know how to fix it.

PS:
If I do it this way, it works, but it's a time-consuming solution to find the max value for every column separately:

```
$a = Get-Content .\numbers.txt
$maximum = 0
foreach ($i in $a) {
    if ([int]$i.Split(";")[0] -gt $maximum) {
        $maximum = $i.Split(";")[0]
    }
}
$maximum
```

Comment: Maximum value for each row or for the whole content?

Answer (score 3):

> I know, there is something wrong with the types (string-integer), but I don't know how to fix it

What's wrong is that `$a` is the *lines* in the file and `$i` is *a line* and you need to split that separately into numbers:

```
$a = get-content .\numbers.txt
$maximum = 0
foreach ( $line in $a )
{
    foreach ( $i in $line.Split(';') )
    {
        if ( [int]$i -gt $maximum )
        {
            $maximum = [int]$i
        }
    }
}
$maximum
```

But also what's wrong is that you're writing (Java/C#/Python/C/otherlang) in PowerShell, this is not good PowerShell habits.

```
Get-Content .\numbers.txt | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.Split(';') } | 
    Measure-Object -Maximum |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum
```

Or if you want it short and type-able:

```
gc .\numbers.txt | foreach split ';' | measure -max
```

Answer (score 1):

For the whole file:

```
Get-Content -Path .\Numbers.txt | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Split(';')
    } | ForEach-Object {
        [int]$_
    } | Measure-Object -Maximum |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Maximum
```

Comment: You probably don't need the cast here and can omit `| ForEach-Object {
        [int]$_
    }`

Comment: Maybe, but I'm on mobile and can't test.  Either way, I'd rather not assume that `Measure-Object` is smart enough to convert strings to ints, or smart enough to evaluate things automagically.  "Maximum" and "Minimum" have conventional definitions for strings, after all.

Comment: `@("1","2", "4", "3") | Measure-Object -Maximum | Select Maximum` outputs `4`. So yes, the 2nd cast can be omitted.

Comment: @Clijsters  No, that doesn't prove it's not sorting strings.  It's definitely doing some form of automagic typing, however, since `'1','23','3'` returns `23`, but `'1','23','3','Test'` returns `Test`.

Comment: How does your observation conflict with mine? If you put a char to a function for measuring numbers, you will either get an exception (your `[int]` cast) or it will just calculate the maximum for that String. (One calls it unexpected behavior, I think it's totally ok to do so)

Comment: Even `@("A", "B", "C", 2, "c", 4, "a") | Measure-Object -Maximum` outputs the correct maximum value.

Comment: @Clijsters Because it depends on what you think the "maximum" of a string is.  Compare `'1','23','3' | Measure-Object -Maximum` to `'1','23','3' | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`.  The latter is how this operation is the conventional "string maximum".  That's what an experienced programmer should expect.

Comment: @Clijsters `Measure-Object` is weird because it tries to parse strings, but it's not all strings that are numbers. Compare `'1','0xf'` and `1, 0xf`.  It recognizes `'1,000'` and `'1e6'` as numeric, too, but it doesn't recognize `'$4'` so it's not even all number styles supported by the TryParse static methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161124/discussion-between-clijsters-and-bacon-bits).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Measure-Object` cmdlet with the `-Maximum` switch do determine the maximum value after you have removed every new line character from the text file and splitting the values:

```
(Get-Content numbers.txt -raw) -replace [system.environment]::NewLine, ';' -split ';' |
     Measure-Object -Maximum |
     Select -ExpandProperty Maximum
```

If your files containing any whitespace character you have to remove them first by adding `-replace '\s+'` before the first `-replace`

Comment: Instead of converting the NewLines to semi-colons how about just expanding your split regex to include them?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `-raw` option of the `Get-Content` which means the whole thing can be done with a simple regex split. Something like this:

```
((Get-Content numbers.txt -raw) -split '[\r\n;]+' | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
```